# Capturing coordinates via snap with QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, georeferencing, snapping

I would like to know if there is a way to get and extract the coordinates of a node (one of the node that conforms a polygon) in order to use these pair of coordinates to georeference a DXF file, using QGIS.

Is there a tool/procedure to do that. I mean, for instance, if there is a way to activate the snapping options for the identify tool, connect the cursor to a concrete node, and get its coordinates.

As far as I know, the Coordinate Capture plugin doesn't allow snapping options and I'm looking for something like that. Any hint or solution?

I'm using QGIS 2.10 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with the plugin "numerical vertex edit"(you can find it in the plugins repostory). There you can edit nodes by clicking on them and then changing their coordinates. The original coordinate is displayed in the edit-window, you can now copy them. Though I'm sure there are more elegant ways, it should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gunnar. Let's see if there is a more elegant way to do it but, it should work for me at this time.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is now called "[NumericalDigitize](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/numericalDigitize/)" (no space between the words)